# How to check the framework of asp.net website using web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How to check the framework of asp.net  website using web.config file.Actually I have website in asp.net I want to check the frame work of asp.net file using web.config file and also i want to know that this website was made in which editor like visual studio 2008 or visual studio 2010 etc..

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it should be in the Web.Config under following categories

Check following tags :

"targetFramework="4.5" /> 
    httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />"

If it is a web application You can right click and check the properties.

.Net Framework  - Visual Studio 
2.0     - 2005 
3.0-3.5 - 2008 
4.0     - 2010 
4.5     - 2012-2013

Comment: Client given me website.I want to know this website has made on in which framework.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the We.config then it will be easier

Comment: which part of web.config file you want because it is confidential

Comment: There is no project file (.csproj or .vbproj). All the files in a folder structure are automatically included in the site.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the information you are looking for is in the project file (*.`vbproj`) rather than in `Web.config`. This is common for any type of project you create in Visual Studio.

If you look into your *.`vbproj` (open this in notepad) file you'll see `ToolsVersion` property and a `TargetFrameworkVersion` tag.

`ToolsVersion` - gives you the `MSBuild` version that's used to build your project
`TargetFrameworkVersion` - gives you the .Net framework used for this project

And, `ProductVersion` will give you the Visual Studio version.

Comment: BUT IN my case no project is present in it.It is a website.So How can i find it in a website

Comment: How can you say you don't have a projec??? Your asp.net application is built as a project. That's how Visual Studio works. Are you looking into your hosted ASP.Net application in IIS? In that case Check the application pool belongs to your website/ web Application.

Comment: No .proj is available.When you create a website.it create a project without .proj

Comment: That's not possible. Search for .csproj extension.

Comment: you need to read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is no project file (.csproj or .vbproj). All the files in a folder structure are automatically included in the site.

Comment: I accept my mistake. It should be .vbproj. Should've looked at the tags. Anyway, Website contains multiple Web applications. So check the version of each by looking at the application pool in IIS as I suggested.

Comment: Actually my client given me only source code,files and folder.